# Create OpenGL core profile under GLFW

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

How do I create a core profile using GLFW and OpenGL?  I'm currently running Mesa 10.0.2 which should support OpenGL 3.3 in a core profile and 3.0 in a non-core profile.

Currently this is what I'm trying to do.

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Create context
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to create context\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I take it that the `glfwOpenWindow()` call in the code you posted returns `false` on your system?  Why aren't you using GLFW3?

Comment: By the way, if you are having trouble with context creation usually you would start by *reducing* the complexity of your pixel format. This means eliminating multi-/supersampling and using a 16- or 24-bit depth buffer (*you are using 4x and 32-bit respectively*). All of the GL window system APIs (GLFW is layered on top of them) provide a pattern matching system for finding suitable pixel formats; the more demanding your requested parameters are, the less likely GLFW is to find a working pixel format.

Comment: You might also consider migrating to [GLFW3](http://www.glfw.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be largely a GLFW version issue as genpfault and Brett Hale pointed out.  Once I ported the offending code to GLFW 3 the issue disappeared.  I also updated to a newer version of the GLM library.  For those who are playing with opengl-tutorial.org, I suggest taking it as an exercise to rewrite the code using updated libraries as the ones supplied are very old at this point.